# Удалить несколько pendingintent из AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager, pendingintent

Имеется список задач. Для задач можно создать несколько напоминаний. Задачи создаются в одной активности, отображается весь их список через ListView в другой. В активности с ListView создал контекстное меню, которое удаляет запись из БД. Но как мне удалить и все её напоминания?
Код функции, который создаёт alarm:

```
private void StartAlarm(long timeAlarm) {
    Random random_idAlarm = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    final int id_alarm = random_idAlarm.nextInt(214748364);

    alarm_for_affair = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent myintent = myintent = new Intent(CreateAffairActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    myintent.putExtra("name", name_affair.getText().toString());
    myintent.putExtra("time", time_affair.getText().toString());

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id_alarm, myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); // конфигурация для напоминания

    alarm_for_affair.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeAlarm, pendingIntent); // запуск таймера
}
```

где **timeAlarm** - время срабатывания. **AlarmReceiver.class** - создаёт notification. Я понял, что надо в AlarmManager передать все данные PendingIntent-ов, удалив их с помощью cancel. Только как мне хранить данные всех интентов для записи и ещё передать их в другую активность не пойму.

Comment: Достаточно сохранить `id_alarm`, например в `Preferences`, и при удалении заново создать PendingIntent c тем же `id_alarm`

Comment: @Serodv а Preferences хранит значения также как и БД? при закрытии приложения, значение переменной не теряется? Просто не знаю что это

Comment: как в обычном файле и проще доступ http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html